# The development team account does not support domains and

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new in IOS development. I would like to transfer my app to my personal iPhone device for first trial run. I followed the video that I found on the internet to sign the IOS app without registering as IOS developer program.
However, everything it seems working fine until the very last part I got an error message telling me that,

> "Your development account does not support domains and push
>   notifications."

I believe this error due to my normal apple id account does not support the push notifications. 
In that case, how could disabled the push notifications in my code? How should resolve this?
Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the free apple developer account, you need to turn off the enabled capabilities.

- Go to target
- Select the Capabilities tab as shown in below image
- Turn off all capabilities (Remote notifications in your case)
- Now run the application on a device with your free account

[image]

Comment: @plc456- you safe my day!

Comment: @DavidB glad to help you. My username is pkc456 not plc456 :)

Comment: Please accept my apologies. But, still one issue here, due to the capabilities of the normal Apple Id account, I've to disabled those restricted functions in my app. Therefore, the app it won't run on my phone eventually. :( . Do you have any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a free developer account here: https://developer.apple.com

After this Xcode will do the stuff automatically if you select Automatically manage signing in the general tab for your target (select your project in the top left in Xcode).

If you want to do it manually you need to create an appId, register your device unique identifier and create a certificate (will need: keychain - request a certificate..) and then a provisioning profile with all of the above, all this in the developer.apple.com platform. Then you must select your provisioning profile in the signing part of the general tab of your target.

[image]

Also make sure under capabilities, all are turned off.

[image]

Comment: @ChrisCh- Thank you for your help, I managed to solve the signing issue. However, my app couldn't run on my iPhone device due to those disabled function.